# Scraping site with jsoup issue

Tags: android, jsoup

When I scrape a site using jsoup I am getting extra values that I do not want to recieve.
I only want to recieve his name not his team and position.  Currently it is also scraping the position and team.  I only want to recieve the name.

Page Source:

```
<td class="playertableData">5</td><td class="playertablePlayerName" id="playername_515" style=""><a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc" instance="_ppc" fpopHeight="357px" fpopWidth="490px" tab="null" leagueId="0" playerId="515" teamId="-2147483648" cache="true">Derrick Rose</a>, Chi&nbsp;PG<a href="" class="flexpop" content="tabs#ppc"
```

My Code:

```
while (tdIter.hasNext()) {
                        int tdCount = 1;
                        Element tdEl = tdIter.next();
                        name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName")
                                .text();

                        Elements tdsEls = tdEl.select("td.playertableData");
                        Iterator<Element> columnIt = tdsEls.iterator();

                        namelist.add(name);
```

OUTPUT:

```
 name: Derrick Rose, Chi PG
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing it wrong. By the line,

```
name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName").text();
```

you will get the complete text of the  with class="playertablePlayerName" which includes an anchor tag and a plane text outside any tag. Means, you will get

```
Derric Rose, Chi PG
```

Which is your output. To solve this issue, you must include the condition for th anchor tag too. Try using the belove line as a replacement.

```
doc = Jsoup_Connect.doHttpGet();
Elements tdsEls = doc.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName");
name = tdsEls.get(0).child(0).text();
```

You can traverse through the child of the td you have already got. When you get correct  tag, use the chained text() method.

Feel free to ask if you have any doubt.

Comment: Thanks!But getting the following error: The method getElementsByTagname(String) is undefined for the type Elements

Comment: Ok, obviously I made a mistake. name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName") will return a list of objects.

I have corrected my answer. Take a look again. If it works, don't forget to accept the answer, click on the tick mark on the left.

Comment: tried again but same reult:name = tdEl.getElementsByClass("playertablePlayerName").get(0).text();

Comment: ok can you pastebin your HTML and code you are using to parse it? I would try to test the code on my side.

Comment: Hi There,
I have seen your paste just today only! I have made a simple application for this question and the code is available here : http://pastie.org/3300889 Also updated my answer.

Thanks

Comment: hey subin can you check my question out at :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9190793/how-to-jsoup-page-with-multiple-tables#comment11575537_9190793

Comment: I have answered there. Please check

Answer (score 0):

You can probably hack up this code to get what you want:

```
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://games.espn.go.com/fba/playerrater?&slotCategoryId=0").get();
    for (Element e : doc.select(".playertablePlayerName")) {
        //this assumes the name is in the first anchor tag
        //which it seems to be according to the url in your pastbin
        System.out.println(e.select("a").first().text()); 
    }
```

To translate to your code, I think this will work...

```
name = tdEl.select("a").first().text();
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Answer (score 0):

Another solutions:

1.- First Name

```
String url = "http://games.espn.go.com/fba/playerrater?&slotCategoryId=0";

    //First Name
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Element e = doc.select("td.playertablePlayerName > a").first();
        String name = e.text(); 
        System.out.println(name);                   
        } 
    catch (IOException e) {             
    }
```

2.- All the names

```
    //All Names
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
        Elements names = doc.select("td.playertablePlayerName > a");
        for( Element e : names )  {
            String name = e.text(); 
            System.out.println(name);
        }

        } 
    catch (IOException e) {             
    }
```